# Prove that $\sum a_{n}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I thought I proved a statement alright, but today I noticed that my professor's solution is quite different from my method, so I would like to know why we could not prove this problem like this (if it is a wrong solution). Please help.

Let $\left ( a_{n} \right )_{n=1}^{\infty }$ be a sequence of real numbers and $s_{k}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +a_{k}$ be the $k$-th
partial sum.

Suppose that $\lim_{}a_{n}=0$, and there exists a $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that the sequence $\left ( s_{mk} \right )_{k=1}^{\infty }=(s_{m},s_{2m},s_{3m}...)$ converges.

Prove that $\sum a_{n}$ converges.

I wanted to used the fact "$\sum a_{n}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=i}^{\infty }a_{n} $ converges for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$" (Starting point doesn't matter.)

My Proof:

Since $s_{m},s_{2m},s_{3m}...$ converges, $s_{2m}-s_{m},s_{3m}-s_{m},s_{4m}-s_{m},...$ all converge.

Thus, $s_{m\infty }-s_{m}$ also converges, which imply $\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty }a_{n}$ converges.

Hence, $\sum a_{n}$ converges. $$\blacksquare $$
However, my professor used the cauchy criterion for this problem, but it is not simple as this.

I wonder why he had to use that method instead of my method which looks simpler.

Thank you.

Comment: The fact that the sequence $(s_m,s_{2m},...)$ converges its **not** the same as saying that all its entries converge for m to infinity. You cannot deduce that $s_{km} - s_m$ converges from your given information.

Comment: Oh maybe that is why my professor used, $0(mod \; m)$. Thanks